# IDE & Debugging of Official SDK for wii and ps3?

Tags: tools, ide

I remember hearing that wii and the ds uses CodeWarrior as their IDE. I know xbox uses visual studios but i have no idea what ps3 uses.

What IDE do ps3 developers use and how do they debug? How do wii programmers debug? I always heard they use GDB but is that built into CodeWarrior or is that a separate application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the Visual Studio IDE for PS3 development -- the PS3 relevant bits are, of course, just command-line tools (GCC ports) that can be plugged in to makefiles that VS can understand, after all.

There's also a toolchain called [ProDG, by SN Systems](http://www.snsys.com/ps3/prodg.asp) that is used for PS3 development.

GDB, as an aside, is its own, command-line program. Some IDEs (such as Xcode on the Mac) have a GUI that wraps it. So it's not "built in" to CodeWarrior or any other IDE, per se, but ships with some as GUI layers some times communicate with it.

Comment: From looking at this it would appear i could use ProDG with any IDE of my choice on the ps3. Would i be able to use GDB?(on ps3). For wii developers they strictly use GDB? i should look more into GDB, it sounds interesting. It sounds like GDB can be used with any language (but i am unsure how it would find source file and line. Maybe any gnu compile embeds that information). I think this answers my question

Comment: GDB is just a command line debugger; it alone isn't all you'd need to develop a game -- and while it is powerful, it can be quite tedious to use. You can use GDB for many platform by virtue of the fact that it's been ported to many -- you'd need to use the rest of the ported GNU toolchain to make it effective.

Comment: And if this does answer your question, please mark it as such :)